# Generating a field not in a structs list

Tags: specman

Say we have a struct which has an int field called idx.
I have a list of this struct and i need to generate an index which isn't in this list.
The most direct keep would be:
    gen idx keeping {
        it not in mylist.idx;
    };

The problem is that if mylist is long, then mylist.idx we return a big list.
I would have prefered to do:
    gen idx keeping {
        not mylist.has(it.idx == it);
    };

Is there any other way to do this, with better memory performance?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed when a list.field returns a new list, and when doing it repetitively, a lot of memory can be allocated.

One way to ease the pain a little is to use an auxiliary list to avoid the use of the "mylist.idx" and an allocation of a new list.

In this way, if your original code was

```
<'  
struct A {
  idx:int;  
};
extend sys  {
    run() is also  {
        var mylist: list of A;
        var idx:int;
        for i from 0 to 10000 {
            gen idx keeping {it not in mylist.idx};
            mylist.add(new A with {.idx = idx;});
        };
    };
};
'>
```

with peak process size: 969MB

you could add an auxiliary list:

```
<'
struct A {
  idx:int;  
};
extend sys  {
    run() is also  {
        var mylist: list of A;
        var l : list of int;
        var idx:int;
        for i from 0 to 10000 {
            gen idx keeping {it not in l};
            mylist.add(new A with {.idx = idx;});
            l.add(idx);
        };
    };
};
'>
```

with peak process size: 736MB

However, since Specman 12.2 you can use the "set" type with the auxiliary variable, which is more effective in generation.

```
<'
struct A {
  idx:int;  
};
extend sys  {
    run() is also  {
        var mylist: list of A;
        var S:set;
        var idx:int;
        for i from 0 to 10000 {
            gen idx keeping {it not in value(S)};
            mylist.add(new A with {.idx = idx;});
            S = S.union([idx]);
        };
    };
};
'>
```

with peak process size: 135MB

Comment: Does this answer the question ? I understood that he wants to generate _ONE_ _INDEX_ _value_ that is not contained in any of the list structs. On the contrary, you create a list with unique indices.

Comment: Indeed the question doesn't specify whether it's one generation, or many. I assumed it's many, since 1) copying a list once doesn't sound problematic, and 2) this is a common usage. For example, this is how you would model sequential writing to many different addresses.  But maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Anyway, I like your solution with the set type, it can also be applied in case he wants to generate just one value not part of the list.

Comment: I need to generate it many times. This solution seems to solve this issue. Thanks